# Check if parent constructor has parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I have got this code:

```
template<class T>
class StackException: public T {
    public:
        StackException(const char* msg): T(msg) {} //<---problem here
}

template<class T>
void myThrow(const &T e) {
    throw StackException<T>(e.what());
}
```

This code works for generic exceptions with a what method, but sometimes the exceptions in my code are defined without any parameter in the constructor. I need a way to enable/disable the constructor of StackException according to the parent constructor. How can I do that with SFINAE? I'm using c++11.

Comment: If the parent class does not have a constructor that takes a `const char *` parameter, do you want your template's constructor to still have the `const char *`  parameter, but ignore it? Or your template's constructor should also not have any parameters; if so sounds like your template constructor should simply take a parameter pack, or even inherit the parent class's constructor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Just ignore it

Comment: I can't use composition or I need to change all catch-es in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specialise via [`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible). You'll have to specialise the whole class, you can't partially specialise just the constructor

```
template<class T, class = std::is_constructible<T, const char *>>
class StackException;

template<class T>
class StackException<T, std::true_type> : public T {
public:
    StackException(const char* msg): T(msg) {} // no problem anymore
};

template<class T>
class StackException<T, std::false_type> : public T {
public:
    StackException(const char* msg): {} // no problem anymore
};
```

However you may find that it's easier to just copy the `T`, rather than it's `what`

```
template<class T>
class StackException : public T {
public:
    StackException(const T & t): T(t) {} // no problem anymore
};

template<class T>
void myThrow(const &T e) {
    throw StackException<T>(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_constructible` is the traits you need to differentiate the case.
You might then use SFINAE, specialization or tag dispatching.

Following example use tag dispatching with delegate constructor:

```
template<class T>
class StackException: public T {
public:
    StackException(const char* msg) :
         StackException(msg, std::is_constructible<T, const char *>{})
    {}

private:
    StackException(const char* msg, std::true_type): T(msg) {}
    StackException(const char* msg, std::false_type): T() {}
};
```